# SingleChildScrollView is not workingg

Tags: flutter, dart

scrol is not working when i used ListView.builder() in SingleChildScrollView  . i have to use ListView.builder() and SingleChildScrollView . do i have a alternative for ListView.builder() and SingleChildScrollView. my app design is irregular , i know and i will fixed .

```
class ListelemeEkrani extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListelemeEkrani({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListelemeEkrani> createState() => _ListelemeEkraniState();
}

class _ListelemeEkraniState extends State<ListelemeEkrani> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [liste()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView liste() {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "yerin adı",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("buraya detay yazısı gelecek" * 2),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.asset("assets/manzara.jpg",
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        fit: BoxFit.contain),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: listeSonucu.values.length,
    );
  }
}

enum listeSonucu { bir, iki, uc, dort, bes, alti, yedi }
```

Answer (score 1):

add scroll physics as **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()** to your listview.

```
ListView liste() {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to directly add a `ListView.builder` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` because both widgets are designed to be scrollable, which can lead to conflicts when used together.

When you use a `ListView.builder`, it creates a scrollable widget that can display a large number of items. On the other hand, a `SingleChildScrollView` creates a scrollable widget that can contain a single child widget.

If you try to nest a `ListView.builder` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`, you will end up with two widgets that are competing for control over the scrolling behavior. This can lead to unexpected results, such as the `ListView.builder` scrolling independently of the `SingleChildScrollView`, or the `SingleChildScrollView` preventing the `ListView.builder` from scrolling.

**To solve this issue we have two answers :**

1. You can consider using a different widget such as a
   `CustomScrollView` which is designed to work with multiple
   scrollable widgets. Or you can wrap the `ListView.builder` with a
   `SizedBox` or `Container` widget that sets a **fixed height**, so that
   the `ListView.builder` doesn't try to scroll beyond its boundaries.
2. Use **`NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`** in sublist

> `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` is a subclass of `ScrollPhysics` in the Flutter framework. It's a special type of **scroll physics** that disables
> scrolling for a given scroll view or scrollable widget.
>
> When you apply `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to a scrollable widget, it
> prevents the widget from scrolling, regardless of whether the user
> attempts to scroll it by dragging or using a scroll controller.

Here's an example of how to use `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to disable scrolling for a ListView widget:

```
ListView.builder(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item $index'),
    );
  },
),
```